# Can't use WiFi in my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS desktop

Tags: network-manager, realtek-wireless, adapter

I have a wireless card and a usb wireless adapter, but I cant get to get either one to work. The only way to have internet is to have a wire connection. Can anyone please help?

```
frank@TMF2:~$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for frank:
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 90:2b:34:d8:41:13
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.0.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7d00000-f7d3ffff ioport:d000(size=128)

  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8190 802.11n PCI Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=64 maxlatency=64 mingnt=32
       resources: ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c00fff
```

***Other Info***

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)

    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev 41)
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8190 802.11n PCI WirelessNetwork Adapter [10ec:8190]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8190 802.11n PCI Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8190]
```

Comment: Your results above show you have a Realtek RTL8190 WiFi controller. See https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Realtek+RTL8190

Answer (score 1):

There is no known native Linux driver for your 10ec:8190 device.

Drivers are typically developed either directly by or in conjunction with the device chipset manufacturer, in this case, Realtek. They have provided no driver for this device.

The alternative used to be to use Windows XP driver files and the ndiswrapper mechanism. However, ndiswrapper is poorly supported and hasn't worked properly on any recent Ubuntu version for many years.

The direct answer to your question is that there is *no solution at all*, including ndiswrapper, to make this work.

I suggest that you purchase another fully supported USB wireless device.

Additional resource: https://github.com/linuxhw/HWInfo/blob/master/README.md#netwireless-pci